# Do I have to call the Base Initialize if I want to override my Controller's Initialize?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class variable that I would like to set up prior to a Controller's method call. It would set the current user up.

I've read that I should do this not on the constructor but by overriding the Initialize method for that specific controller.

I am not familiar on what the original Initialize method does so should I just call it by doing a base.Initialize() prior to the end of the new method?

Is it just better to do this on the constructor or on the Initialize() method?

Comment: Why don't you post some code that supports what you are trying to do?  That would make it much clearer.

Comment: The common rule is to use controller constructor for dependency injection and `Initialize` for initialization tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to. It's clearly stated [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx):

> If you override this method, call the base control's Initialize method.

And, I would avoid relying on the constructor if you're not controlling the instantiation of your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx):

> This method cannot be called directly. Override this method in order
>   to provide additional processing tasks before any ActionResult methods
>   are called, such as setting the thread culture or assigning a custom
>   provider for TempData objects. If you override this method, call the
>   base control's Initialize method.

That means simply override the `Initialize` method. You this will be automatically called when your controller is initialized.

You might not be able to access some controller properties in the constructor because they are not initialized yet (for instance, `Request` property). Therefore it is safe to do your tasks in the `Initialize`.